# Mobile tests: java + appium container + remote adb server + real mobile devices

Tags: java, mobile, appium, adb, docker-container

I am currently developing a testing system for a mobile application.

I'm ran the appium container on my local computer. I started  the ADB server on a separate computer in the local network. Smartphones via USB are connected to the second computer.

I run the container on local computer with the command:

```
docker run -d -p 4723:4723 -e REMOTE_ADB=true -e "ADB_SERVER_SOCKET=tcp:10.38.223.243:5037" --name container-appium-tests ross/appium-tests:v1.0.1

docker exec -it container-appium-tests sh
```

Then, in the container, I run the command

```
adb devices
```

Everything works beautifully and in the container I can see a list of phones connected to the remote computer:

[image]

The problems start when I run the tests `mvn clean test -Dxml=parallel`. The error i am getting:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find a connected Android device in 20026ms. 
Host info: host: '8e41f735a077', ip: '172.17.0.2'
Build info: version: '4.5.0', revision: 'fe167b119a'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.104-linuxkit', java.version: '17.0.4'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:newCommandTimeout=60, appium:appWaitForLaunch=true, appium:resetKeyboard=true, appium:appWaitDuration=60000, appium:appWaitActivity=pl.com.rossmann.centauros.dashboard.presentation.main.DashboardActivity, appium:automationName=UIAutomator2, appium:udid=3691688b, appium:autoGrantPermissions=true, appium:unicodeKeyboard=true, appium:ignoreHiddenApiPolicyError=true, appium:suppressKillServer=true, appium:disableWindowAnimation=true, appium:appActivity=.splash.SplashActivityV6, platformName=ANDROID, appium:enableMultiWindows=true, appium:appPackage=pl.com.rossmann.centauros}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {appium:appActivity: .splash.SplashActivityV6, appium:appPackage: pl.com.rossmann.centauros, appium:appWaitActivity: pl.com.rossmann.centauros.d..., appium:appWaitDuration: 60000, appium:appWaitForLaunch: true, appium:autoGrantPermissions: true, appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:disableWindowAnimation: true, appium:enableMultiWindows: true, appium:ignoreHiddenApiPolicyError: true, appium:newCommandTimeout: 60, appium:resetKeyboard: true, appium:suppressKillServer: true, appium:udid: 3691688b, appium:unicodeKeyboard: true, platformName: ANDROID}}]
Capabilities {}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:144)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:155)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:189)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:547)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:80)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:92)
    at configuration.drivers.Drivers.initializeAndroidDriver(Drivers.java:43)
    at basetest.BaseTest.setUp(BaseTest.java:43)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
... Removed 25 stack frames
```

My class that sets the driver configuration:

```
public abstract class Drivers {

    protected AppiumDriver driver;
    protected AppiumDriverLocalService service;

    protected void initializeAndroidDriver(String udid, int appiumPort) {

        UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();

        options.setAppWaitForLaunch(true);
        options.setNewCommandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60));
        options.setAppWaitDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(60));
        options.setPlatformName("android");
        options.setUdid(udid);
        options.setAutoGrantPermissions(true);
        options.setAppPackage(ConfigProperties.getProperty("app.package"));
        options.setAppWaitActivity(ConfigProperties.getProperty("app.wait.activity"));
        options.setAppActivity(ConfigProperties.getProperty("app.activity"));
        options.setCapability("enableMultiWindows", true);
        options.setDisableWindowAnimation(true);
        options.setSuppressKillServer(true);
        options.setIgnoreHiddenApiPolicyError(true);

        options.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
        options.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);

        try {
            driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:" + appiumPort + "/wd/hub"), options);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

    }

    protected void runAppiumServer() {
        AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                .withArgument(() -> "--base-path", "/wd/hub")
                .withArgument(() -> "--log-level", "error:debug")
                .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1")
                .usingAnyFreePort();
        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
        service.start();
        Logger.info("Appium has been started successfully.");
    }
}
```

Tried with different IP addresses with ports - always similar errors.
I am asking for tips.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you execute `mvn clean test` also inside the container?

Comment: Yes, in a container on the local computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to do remote tests for one device.
In the driver code it is necessary to indicate the remote host, port and device.

```
 UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
 [...]
 options.setRemoteAdbHost("10.38.223.243");
 options.setAdbPort(5038);
 options.setUdid(udid);
```

This resolved the problem described in the question.
However, this only works when one smartphone is connected to the remote server.

When I run the same tests on the same phone, but several phones are connected to the remote server, I have the following error:

```
 Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 
'/opt/android/platform-tools/adb -H 10.38.223.243 -P 5038 -s 8e410c3e forward 
tcp\:8200 tcp\:6790' exited with code 1'; 
Command output: adb: error: more than one device/emulator
```

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
8e410c3e        device     
R58N12HEW3E     device     
RZCT50M61JX     device
```

Ehh, so far I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Selenium grid instead.

http://appium.io/docs/en/2.0/guides/grid/

Comment: Jmerconsulting, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).